# Set mask percent on java gui input

Tags: java, user-interface, format, mask

i have a JTextField in java gui
and i want that the value allways be like this:
nums.nums%

actually i want that allways its add to my double number the percent symbol.

i tried like this:

```
MaskFormatter mf1 = new MaskFormatter("###.##");
mf1.setPlaceholderCharacter('%');
JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(mf1);
```

but its look like this: %%%.%%
and i want
if i write 55 its write 55%

i also tried to use

```
MaskFormatter mf1 = new MaskFormatter("###.##%");
JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(mf1);
```

and its good but the problem that its prevent me to enter a lot of numbers like this:

```
45345345345.44%
```

its only give me three numbers like this:
123.12%
i want
sometimes `1.44%, 22.55%, 223.55%, 45345.12% ....`

tnx a lot...

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
textfield.addFocusListener( e -> {
  @Override
  public void focusLost( final FocusEvent e )
  {
    JTextField textfield = (JTextField) e.getSource();
    textfield.setText(textfield.getText() + "" + "%");
  }
});
```

or at least that's how i'd do it. Haven't tried it tho.